# Want to send mail much quicker using localhost with SMTP?

Tags: php

I'd like to ask if there is a possibility to increase the speed on sending my email from localhost to Gmail using SMTP. It took me about 30 sec before my mail successfully sent. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use a local SMTP server like sendmail in smart host mode to forward emails to Gmail. That way your application can flush the email to local sendmail quickly. Sendmail takes the pain of forwarding the email to gmail.

Comment: Hi Ravih, I'm already using sendmail but my smtp is google's smtp

Comment: If you are using sendmail on localhost with store/forward mode (smart host mode) then there is no way it will take 30 seconds! Please check your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The operation is similar to an email box. For example, the mail () function php directly sending the email. This is not configurable, except perhaps on the side of SMTP server, but it is managed here by GMAIL